# Haskell code for one step redex of abstract machine?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

What should be the type of a single-step reduction function for an abstract machine? `x -> Maybe x` or `x -> x`?

Given such a single-step reduction function, how would one write the multi-step reduction function that gives the normal form of an input term?

Comment: What is `x`? What abstract machine? What should a step do? And probably both types would be fine, the `Maybe` one just mixes signalling termination in the return value.

Comment: Assuming `x` is the type of the state, you also need an argument of type `y`, the thing that causes you to move to a different state.

Comment: It will reduce the function. When applied to a term gives the term obtained after one step execution of abstract machine. 

Suppose x is a datatype to represent terms for a language of arithmetic and boolean expressions.

Comment: As a user, I'd prefer `X -> Maybe X` for a stepping function. A function `X -> X` would not tell me if the term is in normal form or if it is looping on itself.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you want the single-step reduction function to have type `T -> Maybe T`.  Then, for redexes you return a `Just`, and for normal forms you return `Nothing`.  This follows a general principle that functions should return as much of the information they compute to the caller as possible, which helps reduce re-computation in your program.

If your single-step reduction function is `singleStepReduce :: T -> T`, it has two choices when given an argument which is already in normal form:

- Return the argument.  This requires the caller to do something like `x == singleStepReduce x` or `isNF x` to determine if the argument is in NF; this is information `singleStepReduce` is already determining, so it's wasted computation; furthermore, `x == singleStepReduce x` is very computationally expensive, while `isNF x` still duplicates that determination *and* allows the rules for reduction and the rules for determining normal forms to fall out of step, which violates basic software engineering principles.
- Return `undefined`.  This is worse; it means the caller has no way to recover from the normal-form case, forcing the caller to use `isNF x` before calling `singleStepReduce x`, and leaving the problem that the definitions of `isNF x` and `singleStepReduce x` implement overlapping logic unsolved.

Implementing a multi-step reducer, provided you're ok with the reducer going into an infinite loop on terms that lack a normal form, is then pretty simple:

```
multiStepReduce :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a
multiStepReduce r x = case r x of
    Nothing -> x
    Just y -> multiStepReduce r y
```

Comment: Even worse, `x == singleStepReduce x` is not equivalent to `isNF x` when `x` has a self-looping transition.